# IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies Collection is empty and Append does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, .net-6.0

I have a .Net Core 6 web application using razor web pages. I am converting the front end to a javascript UI and have added controllers to the project to service the Ajax calls. The controllers call 'manager' classes for their business logic that are using normal dependency injection (DI).

For the existing web pages, I am calling a manager that gets and set cookies using the **IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies** that is passed in using DI. It has been working fine and I see can 6 cookies.

If I call the same code in the manager class from the controllers using one of the Ajax calls - the cookies collection is empty. Furthermore, if I add the basic code below to add a cookie, as a test inline to the existing code, no cookie is visible after the code has processed (and with no errors).

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Test", "TestValue");
```

I am using the DI code below in my Startup.cs

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and have tried adding

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and I have also experimented with various **CookieOptions** but so far no luck.

Any ideas as to why the code is not working when being run from the controllers but works from the web pages?

ADDED (per Guru request):

Here is the code in the manager:

```
public class AppManager : IAppManager
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

  public AppManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor )
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  public string ReadCookie(string key)
  {  
    // ADDED THIS LINE BELOW - BUT IT DOES NOTHING
    // STARTS WITH 0 COOKIES AND IS 0 COOKIES EVEN AFTER THE APPEND
    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Test", "TestValue");

    var data = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[key];

    return data;
  }

  public void WriteCookie(string key, string value, int? daysToPersist = null)
  {
    // HAVE TRIED VARIOUS OPTIONS HERE
    var options = new CookieOptions 
    { 
        SameSite    = SameSiteMode.None,
        Secure      = true,
        IsEssential = true,
        HttpOnly    = false
    };

    if (daysToPersist > 0)
        options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays((double)daysToPersist);
    else
        options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((double)60);

    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, options);

  }

  public void DeleteCookie(string key)
  {
    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
  }

}
```

Here is the code in the Controller:

```
public Guid GetUserGuidFromCookie()
{
    string userGuidString = ReadCookie(UserGuidKey);
    if (!Guid.TryParse(userGuidString, out Guid userGuid))
    {
        userGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        WriteCookie(UserGuidKey, userGuid.ToString(), 14);
    }
    return userGuid;
}
```

Added Program.cs 7/28/2023

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
   }

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
}
```

Added Startup.cs 7/28/2023

```
public class Startup
{
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
 {
    Configuration = configuration;
 }

 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                      options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                }
            );

    services.AddRazorPages()  //.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddRazorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
            });


    services.AddSingleton<IAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("App").Get<AppSettings>());
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();         
    
    services.AddScoped<IAppManager, AppManager>();


    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ApiPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

 }

 public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
                        IDataRepo dataRepo)
 {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");  
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: When you call the manager class from the controllers using an AJAX call, the HttpContext may not be available in the same way as it is in the regular web pages. This is because AJAX calls are typically made from JavaScript running on the client-side, and the HttpContext is specific to server-side requests.

Comment: Allanckw - Yeah, I get the difference between server and client cookies, but I am not trying to write the cookie client-side then pick it up on the server-side within the HttpContext. This is usually where you see those kind of issues. I am trying to both read and write on the server, even in the same function. But obviously I am missing something in how it works.

Comment: Please show the full code where you are trying to access and set cookies. In ASP.NET Core controllers there is no need to use the `HttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: Guru Stron - The controller is calling the manager. I add code to show what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas as to why the code is not working when being run from the
> controllers but works from the web pages?

Well, based on my investigation and test, you are experiencing this issue because of incorrect DI invocation.

First of all, you haven't registered `AppManager` service within your program.cs file in .NET 6 appliction which should register in DI.

Another important point is that, you don't need to register `IHttpContextAccessor` the way you did. Instead you can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Most importantly, while working with cookie your application state should be persistent but if you use [TryAddSingleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.servicecollectionmap.tryaddsingleton?view=efcore-7.0) app state woundn't be peristent in http request because in every request previous instance would be ommitted. This is how the singleton service has designed.

Thus, according to your scenario and context, you should use [AddScoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) service in order to maintain your app state persistent and not to override previous initialization.

**Solution:**

Let's wrap up, I have used your code snippet in following way and working as expected:

Update Your Write Cookie Configuration:

```
var options = new CookieOptions
            {
               // SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                Secure = true,
                IsEssential = true,
                HttpOnly = false
            };
```

[image]

**Note:** If you use `SameSiteMode.None`, you also have to set the "HttpOnly" property to true. The cookie will work with https only. But if you want set https as false, then you can comment  `SameSite = SameSiteMode.None`. [Please have a look this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Program.cs:

In your code snippet, you haven't register AppManager DI and also, you can register AddHttpContextAccessor as following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppManager, AppManager>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Controller:

```
public class CookieManagerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppManager _cookieManager;

        public CookieManagerController(IAppManager appManager)
        {
            _cookieManager = appManager;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _cookieManager.WriteCookie("TestCookieKey", "Kiron Test", 30);
            ViewBag.CookieName = _cookieManager.ReadCookie("TestCookieKey");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to the official document for more details implementation and guidelines.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0#api-usage-with-samesite)

Comment: Md Farid Uddin Kiron - Thanks for taking a look. The DI is working fine, it was just not something I posted here. Remember the code works, just not from the Ajax call. It could be something like the scope of the of the services and I will look into that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, yes scope causing the issue which I have found in my test. Let me know, if  you need any further assistance on this.